# .htaccess file not working even i am giving all the details which required

Tags: php, .htaccess

my .htaccess file whole code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /id/(.*)\.php detail.php?id=$1
```

i have some featured image in index page when i click to it ,it goes to detail page with a id like..http://tinmandevserver.com/demo//kingstate/detail.php?id=1
i go to the tool which convert my dynamic url into static url 
http://www.iwebtool.com/htaccess_url_rewrite?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftinmandevserver.com%2Fdemo%2Fkingstate%2Fdetail.php%3Fid%3D1&ext=.php&sep=%2F  i got the code from there nd i put it into my htaccess file but the detail page url are not convrted to static url when i click to the featured image on index page..please help this is first time i work on it.

Comment: make sure your rewrite module is enabled :) google about how to enable rewrite module

Comment: are u talking about RewriteEngine???

Comment: make sure the option  Allowoverride All is in your directory configuration in apache config file

Comment: m not getting how to put a 'Allowoverride aLL ' in my htaccess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in `/demo/kingstate/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo/kingstate/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /detail\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ id/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^id/([0-9]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: still not working...:(

Comment: What is location of .htaccess and what URL did you try?

Comment: what do you mean by location???.htaccess file are put in the folder where my whole php pages are located..and the url i try is..http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/detail.php?id=1

Comment: I mean is .htaccess inside `/demo/kingstate/` path?

Comment: try updated code now.

Comment: yes my htacess file are in the http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate bt your code is not working..:(

Comment: yes it is working now..but the page css are messed up..you can check...http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/index.php ..click the featured image

Comment: For css/js issue use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR else you can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: yes it is working now thank u so much...but now u can check http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/detail.php/id/1 it didn't get id

Comment: Because that's not the correct pretty link. Link should be: `http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/kingstate/id/1`

Comment: m giving the http tag but when m click, it redirect to normal again tinamn...

Comment: Sorry didn't understand what you mean by `it redirect to normal again tinamn`?

Comment: how we make link which u mentioned above???

Comment: I don't know about HTML/PHP code. But in HTML it will be like `<a href="/demo/kingstate/id/1">GE-167,victoria,melbourn</a>`

Comment: m giving like <a href="http://tinmandevserver.com/demo/detail.php?id=<?php echo $prt_row['id'];?>">property</a> not working..:(

Comment: See this is going well beyond the answer I provided. Answer is for URL rewriting not for PHP coding. I suggest you create a new question for that problem to get better answer from SO community and close this question by accepting it.

Comment: k thank u for ur hlp..:)

Comment: Welcome, but don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.